# Dart set default value for parameter

Tags: flutter, dart

in `Flutter` framework i'm trying to set default value for parameters as `borderRadius`, in this sample how can i implementing that? i get `Default values of an optional parameter must be constant` error when i try to set that, for example:

```
class SimpleRoundButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final BorderRadius borderRadius;
  SimpleRoundButton({
  }):this.borderRadius = BorderRadius.circular(30.0);
}


class SimpleRoundButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final BorderRadius borderRadius= BorderRadius.circular(30.0);
  SimpleRoundButton({
    this.borderRadius,
  });
}


class SimpleRoundButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final BorderRadius borderRadius;
  SimpleRoundButton({
    this.borderRadius=  BorderRadius.circular(30.0)
  });
}
```

all of this samples are incorect

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`BorderRadius.circular()` is not a const function so you cannot use it as a default value.

To be able to set the const circular border you can use `BorderRadius.all` function which is const like below:

```
class SimpleRoundButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final BorderRadius borderRadius;
  SimpleRoundButton({
    this.borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0))
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

[Gunhan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56481890/179715) explained how you can set a default `BorderRadius`.

In general, if there isn't a `const` constructor available for the argument type, you instead can resort to using a `null` default value (or some other appropriate sentinel value) and then setting the desired value later:

```dart
class Foo {
  Bar bar;

  Foo({Bar? bar}) : bar = bar ?? Bar();
}
```

Note that explicitly passing `null` as an argument will do something different with this approach than if you had set the default value directly.  That is, `Foo(bar: null)` with this approach will initialize the member variable `bar` to `Bar()`, whereas with a normal default value it would be initialized to `null` and require that the member be nullable. (In some cases, however, this approach's behavior might be more desirable.)

Answer (score 1):

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  // Declare a parameter with a default value using curly braces
  final String message;

  // Constructor with the default value provided for the parameter
  MyStatelessWidget({this.message = 'Hello, World!'});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Stateless Widget Example')),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(message),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyStatelessWidget(),
  ));
}
```

for more details you can refer : https://flutterwebbies.com/flutter/tutorial/how-to-set-default-value-for-parameter/