# Initializing member with constructor in an optional parameter constructor in Dart

Tags: dart, constructor, optional-parameters

Based on my following code, I want to have a **constructor** of the class `Hero` that takes a `Stats` class as an **optional parameter** that has a **default value based on its constructor** *(the one that set its health and attack fields to 100 and 10  by an optional named parameter)* **instead of null**.

```dart
void main() {
  Hero hero = Hero("Foo");
  print('${hero.name} : HP ${hero.stats.health}');
}
class Stats {
  Stats({this.health = 100, this.attack = 10});
  double health;
  double attack;
}
class Hero {
  // error: The default value of an optional parameter must be constant
  Hero(this.name,[this.stats = Stats()]);
  String name;
  Stats stats;
}
```

More things i've tried:

```
class Hero {
  // error: Can't have a const constructor for a class with non-final fields
  Hero(this.name,[this.stats = const Stats()]);
  String name;
  Stats stats;
}
```

```
class Hero {
  // error: stats initialized as null
  Hero(this.name,[this.stats]);
  String name;
  Stats stats = Stats();
}
```

This following code works but it doesn't have stats as an optional parameter:

```
class Hero {
  Hero(this.name);
  String name;
  Stats stats = Stats();
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56489812/179715

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(Credits to [@jamesdlin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/179715/jamesdlin) for linking to [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56489812/179715) in the comments)*

> In general, if there isn't a const constructor available, you instead
> can resort to using a null default value (or some other appropriate
> sentinel value) and then setting the desired value later:

```dart
class Foo {
  Bar bar;

  Foo({Bar bar}) : bar = bar ?? Bar();
}
```

> (Note that explicitly passing null as an argument will do something
> different with this approach than if you had set the default value
> directly. That is, Foo(bar: null) with this approach will initialize
> bar to Bar(), whereas with a normal default value it would initialize
> bar to null. In some cases, however, this approach's behavior might be
> more desirable.)