# Not able to access static value, which is constant in Flutter, Dart

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am trying to access a static value which is stored in app.dart
[Class and static variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06Wea.png)

I have set the value of this variable in splashscreen.dart
[Setting and printing the values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfLSi.png)

Here in
[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR3Jj.png)

But shows error, that it requires static value only in login_register
[Error while accessing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPAeE.png)

Guide me, if I am doing something wrong.

Thank you

Comment: The error message tells you what's wrong: default values to optional parameters must be constants.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56489812/ for what you can do if you can't make it a constant.

Comment: Yes, value needs to be constant and in each and every way, _Device.width_ passed is constant, best of my knowledge, then why it doesn't fetch that or is it a dynamic value passed, which its doesn't entertain?

Comment: `Device.width` is a getter.  Is it not a compile-time constant.  Constants are declared with `const`.

Comment: Yup solved the issue, Thanks