# Flutter VoidCallback field default value in Constructor

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor

This should be an easy answer but I do not find the solution yet on the internet.

Let say I have 1 `VoidCallback` field name `onStart` in a constructor, and I want this field to have a default value when there is no parameter pass it to the constructor. I already try some code but the IDE gives me a warning. How to provide this default value?

```dart
class DefaultCallbackExample {
  final VoidCallback onStart;
  final VoidCallback onFinish;
  final bool isEnable;

  DefaultCallbackExample({
    this.onStart = (() => {}), // IDE Warning
    required this.onFinish,
    this.isEnable = true,
  });
}
```

```dart
class DefaultCallbackExample {
  final VoidCallback onStart;
  final VoidCallback onFinish;
  final bool isEnable;

  DefaultCallbackExample({
    this.onStart = const (() => {}), // IDE Warning
    required this.onFinish,
    this.isEnable = true,
  });
}
```

There is a solution from [jamesdin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68702739/11235449), but I hope there is a simpler solution not to have to write `constant sentinel value`. Maybe in the future dart version, there is a possible solution

Comment: Why did you wrap ( ) => in ( )?

Comment: If I'm not wrapping it, it still not working

Comment: You should let it be null, and then where you want to call it: onStart?.call(); This way you won’t get an exception when no value is passed in.

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but I don't want it to be null.

Answer (score 10):

Either the callback should be nullable or it must be initialized with a default value.  Default arguments must be constants, so as usual, if you can't provide a constant directly, [use a constant sentinel value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56489812/):

```dart
class DefaultCallbackExample {
  final VoidCallback onStart;
  final VoidCallback onFinish;
  final bool isEnable;

  DefaultCallbackExample({
    VoidCallback? onStart,
    required this.onFinish,
    this.isEnable = true,
  }) : onStart = onStart ?? (() {});
}
```

Also note that `() => {}` creates an anonymous function that returns an empty `Set`.  An anonymous function with an empty body should be just `() {}`.  Function bodies either should use `=>` (if possible) or curly braces, but not both.

Comment: Yes I know this solution, but I hope there is a simple similar like this code `this.onStart = const (() => {})`

Comment: If you're unwilling to create a named function, then no.  You can't use `const` with a lambda, and `Function` is an abstract class without a `const` constructor.

Comment: @NMNaufaldo See https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1048.

Answer (score 1):

Create a static method that will be the default value of the function in your class.

```
class Class{
  final Function function;
  Class({this.function = _defaultFunction});
  static _defaultFunction() {}
}
```

Comment: This solution work, but I think it's a little bit ugly.