# this.reference is not working on flutter/dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't know what's the problem here but i get an error on [this.reference], it says "The parameter 'reference' can't have a value of 'null' because of its type, but the implicit default value is 'null'."
When I add required it says "Can't have modifier 'required' here"

Here's the code for it:

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class Request {
  final String type;
  final String reason;
  DocumentReference reference;

  Request(this.reason, this.type, [this.reference]);

  String get requestId {
    return reference.id;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {"type": type, "reason": reason};
  }
}
```

Comment: if you like to make optional parameter use `{...}`

Comment: add null check operator '?' , like DocumentReference? reference;

Comment: @YeasinSheikh The parameter already is optional.  Curly braces make a parameter *named*.

Comment: @RajaEhtisham `?` is not a null check operator.  A type ending with `?` is *nullable*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Request {
  final String type;
  final String reason;
  DocumentReference? reference;

  Request(this.reason, this.type, [this.reference]);

  String get requestId {
    return reference!.id;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {"type": type, "reason": reason};
  }
}
```

Guessing you are running on null-safety, you may want to make `DocumentReference` nullable

Answer (score 0):

Did u tried making those **Nullable**

```
final String? type;
final String? reason;
```

**Also Try** Giving default initial values

```
Request(String reason = '',String type = '');
```

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets around a parameter make that parameter an *optional positional parameter*.  Therefore when you write:

```dart
Request(this.reason, this.type, [this.reference]);
```

You are specifying that the `Request` constructor take two required positional parameters (`reason` and `type`) and an optional positional parameter (`reference`).

If you want `reference` be optional, it must have a default value if the caller doesn't provide it.  Your options are:

- Provide a `const`, non-null default value:

  ```dart
  Request(
     this.reason,
     this.type,
     [this.reference = DocumentReference.someConstConstructor()],
  );
  ```

  (The [`DocumentReference` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/DocumentReference-class.html) from `package:cloud_firestore` does not provide a `const` constructor, so you can't do this in your case, but I've listed it here for completeness.)
- Make `reference` nullable so that it can use `null` as an implicit default value:

  ```dart
  class Request {
    ...
    DocumentReference? reference;
    ...
    Request(this.reason, this.type, [this.reference]);
  ```

  or if you want a nullable parameter with a non-nullable member:

  ```dart
  class Request {
    ...
    DocumentReference reference;
    ...
    Request(this.reason, this.type, [DocumentReference? reference])
      : reference = reference ?? DocumentReference();
  ```

  The latter is [a general technique for making parameters optional when the parameter type has no `const` constructors available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56489812/).
- Make `reference` non-optional.  Since using square brackets around a parameter make that parameter optional, adding the `required` keyword would be a contradiction and would make no sense.  If you want it to be a required positional parameter, simply remove the square brackets:

  ```dart
  Request(this.reason, this.type, this.reference);
  ```

  Or if you want to be a required *named* parameter, use curly braces with the `required` keyword:

  ```dart
  Required(this.reason, this.type, {required this.reference});
  ```

I suggest reading the [Functions Parameters section of the Dart Language Tour](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#parameters).